# Apache Solr date range query

Tags: apache, solr

I have just started learning Solr, and I am stuck in making query that takes document which is greater than 2 months old.

I did the query like: `q=createdate:[* TO NOW/MONTH-2MONTHS]` but it returns nothing. I have some documents that are 2 months old or greater.

What did I do wrong? Can someone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: Try: q=createdate:[* TO NOW-2MONTHS/MONTH]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out by using this:
`q=createdate[* TO NOW-2MONTHS]`